# how to continue text under image in column in bootstrap html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am creating a box with bootstrap, like following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
  .addonscard {
    width: 100%;
    height: 181px;
    padding: 2%;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
  }
  
  .addonsimage {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    color: #30ac15;
    border: 1px solid #30ac15;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 2px 12px 2px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    color: #30ac15;
    border: 1px solid #30ac15;
  }
  
  .addonsdesc {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
</style>


<section class="addons">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="addonscard">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="addonsimage" src="test1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <h4>This is Heading</h4>
              <p>Price</p>
              <a href="" class="add-on-add-unit">+ Add</a>
              <p class="addonsdesc">Standard photography at best value to turn make lifetime memories from your party. Photographer will be available for maximum 3 hours. 150 - 200 soft copies will be delivered through CD within 10 working days from the event date.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

as you can see the text is going out of the box, i want the text to be like a continuation under image , something like below:

[image]

because both image and text is on different columns, am not able to put it like this, am new to bootstrap, can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this. thanks in advance

Comment: I think you will have to use `float:left` and fixed-width image instead of grid or flexbox.

Comment: You can't achieve that with image and text both in different columns. You will have to use  `align="left"` in  `img` tag, or eventually use `float:left `

Comment: but then will it affect my responsiveness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a specific height in .addonscard. If you are giving specific height then you have to give overflow property. I have added overflow property in my answer.
Hope this helps.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
  .addonscard {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2%;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    overflow:auto;
  }
  
  .addonsimage {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    color: #30ac15;
    border: 1px solid #30ac15;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 2px 12px 2px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    color: #30ac15;
    border: 1px solid #30ac15;
  }
  
  .addonsdesc {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
</style>


<section class="addons">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="addonscard">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="addonsimage" src="test1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <h4>This is Heading</h4>
              <p>Price</p>
              <a href="" class="add-on-add-unit">+ Add</a>
              <p class="addonsdesc">Standard photography at best value to turn make lifetime memories from your party. Photographer will be available for maximum 3 hours. 150 - 200 soft copies will be delivered through CD within 10 working days from the event date.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: no, its not fixing the issue, instead its giving me scroll buttons

Comment: then give height:auto to .addonscard

Comment: and if you are giving height: auto then you don't need overflow property.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this -

```
<section class="addons">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="addonscard">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <img class="addonsimage" src="img/Android-Lollipop-wallpapers-Google-Now-Wallpaper-2.png" />
                <h4>This is Heading</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
                <a href="" class="add-on-add-unit">+ Add</a>
                <p class="addonsdesc">Standard photography at best value to turn make lifetime memories from your party. Photographer will be available for maximum 3 hours. 150 - 200 soft copies will be delivered through CD within 10 working days from the event date.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

.addonscard {
      width: 100%;
      height: 181px;
      padding: 2%;
      border: 1px solid #efefef;
    }

    .addonsimage {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .add-on-add-unit {
      color: #30ac15;
      border: 1px solid #30ac15;
    }

    .add-on-add-unit {
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      padding: 2px 12px 2px 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .add-on-add-unit {
      color: #30ac15;
      border: 1px solid #30ac15;
    }

    .addonsdesc {
      font-size: 13px;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, When you are adding an answer, you must also add a comment.  How and what was the issue, and how did you solve it.